# Difference between text and string in sails.js

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Going through waterline docs: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/data-types-attributes.md left me wondering,

What's the difference between `string` and `text` data types in waterline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One difference is the column definition that is created by `sails-mysql`

`string` creates a `VARCHAR` column
`text` creates a `LONGTEXT` column

Ref: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql/blob/0.11.x/lib/sql.js#L375

Comment: Thanks. That solves that for me, but I guess would be interesting what other adapters have for that difference